# Implementing global Assumptions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

Why do the following commands

```
$Assumptions = {Element[x, Reals], x > 0};
Solve[{x^2 == 1}, {x}]
Solve[{x^2 == -1}, {x}]
```

give

```
(*{{x -> -1}, {x -> 1}}*)
(*{{x -> -I}, {x -> I}}*)
```

Wouldn't I expect to get only

```
(*{x -> 1}*)
```

Furthermore, how can I implement global assumptions that hold for the entire session? I have quite a lot of Simplify[] and they all use the same variables which I want to be real and positive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The appropriate command should be :

`Solve[x^2 == 1 && x > 0, x, Reals]`
`Solve[x^2 == -1 && x > 0, x, Reals]`

The third argument is the domain specification and the `x>0` is an extra constraint you need to specify.

This gives the results `{{x -> 1}}` and `{}` respectively.

When Mathematica solves your equation it treats $x$ as a dummy variable and, hence, is ignoring the global assumptions on $x$.

Comment: Thanks! So there is no way to declare x as real and positive for all calculations without having to write it as you wrote it above?

Comment: @xabdax not while using `Solve`. You can use global assumptions to simplify other expressions where $x$ is not treated as a dummy variable -- `$Assumptions = And[x>0,Element[x,Reals]]` should work for those other cases.

Comment: `x>0` automatically implies `x ∈ Reals`, so it can be omitted in the assumptions

Comment: If you evaluate `Options[Solve]` you will see that the options do not include `Assumptions` and consequently `Solve` does not make use of `$Assumptions`. The assumptions must be included as constraints in the system provided to `Solve`. Subsequent use of `Simplify` or `FullSimplify` would make use of `$Assumptions` since their options include `Assumptions` (`$Assumptions` is the default value for `Assumptions`).